# How to recover tables info from select data using python and cx_Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I have multiple Oracle Queries like this one executed with Cx_Oracle in my python script

```
Select  bo.lxname, bt.mxname, bo.lxrev, bo.lxcrdate, bo.lxmoddate, uss.mxname, pol.mxname, st.mxname 
from pdm.lxbo_5DC2EDE2 bo 
INNER JOIN pdm.mxbustype bt ON bo.lxtype = bt.mxoid 
INNER JOIN pdm.mxuser uss ON bo.lxowner = uss.mxoid 
INNER JOIN pdm.mxpolicy pol ON bo.lxpolicy = pol.mxoid 
INNER JOIN pdm.mxstatereq st ON bo.lxstate = st.mxoid 
where bo.Lxoid = '713307622'
```

I know that I can use .description from the cursor to recover informations like :

```
    cur = cx.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    desc = cur.description
```

But the description only returns me columns name :

```
[('LXNAME', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_VARCHAR>, 128, 128, None, None, 1), ('MXNAME', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_VARCHAR>, 128, 128, None, None, 1), ('LXREV', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_VARCHAR>, 128, 128, None, None, 1), ('LXCRDATE', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_DATE>, 23, None, None, None, 1), ('LXMODDATE', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_DATE>, 23, None, None, None, 1), ('MXNAME', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_VARCHAR>, 128, 128, None, None, 1), ('MXNAME', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_VARCHAR>, 128, 128, None, None, 1), ('MXNAME', <cx_Oracle.DbType DB_TYPE_VARCHAR>, 128, 128, None, None, 1)]
```

As you can see there are multiple mxname but there is no way with this information to tell this "mxname" is associated to this table in my code.

I have searched for more information inside the cursor but I've found nothing regarding tables.

Is there any simple way for me to recover the table associated with the column in my python script ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to find out what table a particular column comes from in you query simply by examining the cursor description. You could, however, use an alias in your query, as in the following:

```
Select
    bo.lxname as bo_lxname,
    bt.mxname as bt_mxname,
    bo.lxrev as bo_lxrev,
    bo.lxcrdate as bo_lxcrdate,
    bo.lxmoddate as bo_lxmoddate,
    uss.mxname as uss_maxname,
    pol.mxname as pol_maxname,
    st.mxname as st_mxname
from pdm.lxbo_5DC2EDE2 bo 
INNER JOIN pdm.mxbustype bt ON bo.lxtype = bt.mxoid 
INNER JOIN pdm.mxuser uss ON bo.lxowner = uss.mxoid 
INNER JOIN pdm.mxpolicy pol ON bo.lxpolicy = pol.mxoid 
INNER JOIN pdm.mxstatereq st ON bo.lxstate = st.mxoid 
where bo.Lxoid = '713307622'
```

With this query, cursor.description will contain information that will tell you what table it came from.

Comment: Yeah that's a sort of solution ! 
But the final goal I imagined was to make something generic to avoid  making a dictionary with  translation between alias and tables as I have tons of tables, columns and queries.

Was thinking about a query scrapper to find which alias belongs to which table to rebuild the structure and link the cursor description as it is in the select order. But I don't know if it is a good and clean way to achieve this.